# Redirection With https from www to non-www

Tags: redirect

I have very simple requirement, I want a set of RewriteRule which can do the following things

1. Redirect all www request to non-www.
2. Redirect all request to https.

Ultimately my URL requirement is like `http://domain.com`
I am able to do most things but a request like https://www.domain.com is not redirecting.

This my redirection rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Please suggest what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below

```
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect HTTP with www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTPS with www to HTTPS without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```